# Making Http request to Server to email - Android

Tags: java, php, android, email

I'm making an android application. My application has a quiz. When the user passes the quiz they are emailed a certificate. I am doing this by making a http request to a server and the email is sent through php. I got it to work with just the email body but I also want the user to be able to enter their email address (in the application) and the php file should get this from the code.

Here is my code when I just had the email body (which worked) and sent it to myself

```
new HttpPosting().execute("http://saf=fo.com/brEmail.php?emailBody="+ "HeyYOUUUUU");
```

Here is what I tried to add the email recipient (doesn't work)

```
new HttpPosting().execute("http://sainfo.com/bredanSendEmail.php?emailBody="
                        + "HeyYOUUUUU"+"?emailTo="+"brendan@hotmail.com");
```

here is the php file on the server:

```
<?php

$body = $_GET['emailBody'];
$headers = 'From: IFA Safeguarding App <welfare@irishfa.com>';
$to = $_GET['emailTo'];

$subject = "Email from IFA Safeguarding in Football App";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "0";
}

?>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: sorry pasted it wrong..did have the =....still didn't work

Comment: you are missing "&". remove the "?"

Comment: As a side note, you are creating a massive spam gateway. I (you) sent you an email ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your URL to:

```
new HttpPosting().execute("http://safeandsecureinfo.com/brendanSendEmail.php?emailBody="
                        + "HeyYOUUUUU"+"&emailTo="+"brendan@hotmail.com");
```

**NOTE:**

**Please note that the php code is very insecure as the php file can be accessed by anyone, meaning a spammer can send thousands of emails from your server, to anyone they choose**

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the spam implications of this code, in case anyone else thinks its a good idea (its certainly **NOT**)

Comment: @Steve I just want to help him i.e solve his problem. Maybe he will encrypt/obfuscate the data in the url..

Comment: Of course, and im not saying you answer is wrong or bad, just that it would be better if you edit it to include a warning, something like **"Please note that the php code is very insecure as the php file can be accessed by anyone, meaning a spammer can send thousands of emails from your server, to anyone they choose"**